# Cannot load module 'swiftyjson' as 'SwiftyJSON'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, podfile

I install whatever pods it cannot run.

It shows one error:

> Cannot load module swiftyjson as SwiftyJSON

How do I fix it?

Comment: are you implement this on the top of the class : import SwiftyJSON

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is currently not very clear. Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is that you are facing and what you've tried so far to fix the issue. Also, consider posting relevant code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: can you add some additional code